# Get data and insert it using loop (MSQL/I)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, mysqli

I select data from table A and what I want is to insert that data using a loop.

Here's my code:

```
    $getlvls = "SELECT * FROM `access_chart` WHERE `ac_id`='$data->ac_id'";
    $qry99 = $con->query($getlvls);
    while($row = $qry99->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lvl1 = $row['lvl1'];
        $lvl2 = $row['lvl2'];
        $lvl3 = $row['lvl3'];
        $lvl4 = $row['lvl4'];
    }

    for($jaa = 1; $jaa <=4; $jaa++){
        $auth_id = '$lvl'+$jaa;
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `overtime_log`(`ot_id`, `lvl`, `user_id`) VALUES('$ot_id', $jaa, '$auth_id')";
        $qry = $con->query($sql1);
    }
```

I don't include all of my codes. Everything works, except for inserting the column `$lvl1`, `$lvl2`, `$lvl3` and `$lvl4` using a loop. Or if you would suggest other logic that's find.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

```
Select the data:

|----------------|
|--access_chart--| TABLE
|----------------|
-------------------
|---------|---------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|--ac_id--|--access_name--|--lvl1--|--lvl2--|--lvl3--|--lvl4--|
|---------|---------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|    1    |   MIS Dept    |    4   |    5   |    9   |    0   |



This might be the output after INSERT QUERY:


|----------------|
|--overtime_log--| TABLE
|----------------|
-------------------
|---------|-------|-----------|
|--ot_id--|--lvl--|--user_id--|
|---------|-------|-----------|
|    1    |   1   |     4     |
|    1    |   2   |     5     |
|    1    |   3   |     9     |
|    1    |   4   |     0     |
```

Comment: If it works, what's the problem?

Comment: @Ultimater, Everything works, except for inserting column `lvl1`, `lvl2`, `lvl3` and `lvl4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where `$ot_id` is defined, but assuming you're using only ids and SQL injection isn't a concern, you could use something like:

```
$getlvls = "SELECT * FROM `access_chart` WHERE `ac_id`='$data->ac_id'";
$qry99 = $con->query($getlvls);
while($row = $qry99->fetch_array())
{
    foreach(array(1=>$row['lvl1'],2=>$row['lvl2'],3=>$row['lvl3'],4=>$row['lvl4']) as $key=>$lvl)
    {
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `overtime_log`(`ot_id`, `lvl`, `user_id`) VALUES('$ot_id', $key, '$lvl')";
        $qry = $con->query($sql1);      
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could avoid the inner loop altogether and just write the INSERT using multiple-insert syntax:

```
$getlvls = "SELECT * FROM `access_chart` WHERE `ac_id`='$data->ac_id'";
$qry99 = $con->query($getlvls);
while($row = $qry99->fetch_array())
{
    $con->query("INSERT INTO `overtime_log`(`ot_id`, `lvl`, `user_id`)
    VALUES('$ot_id', 1, '{$row['lvl1']}'),
    ('$ot_id', 2, '{$row['lvl2']}'),
    ('$ot_id', 3, '{$row['lvl3']}'),
    ('$ot_id', 4, '{$row['lvl4']}')");
}
```

Comment: I updated my question and added a visual presentation on how the data is selected and inserted.

Comment: Before your update, I thought your problem was caused by `while($row = $qry99->fetch_assoc()) {` since you'd be looping all the results and not be storing the rows in an array. But after your update, it looks like `ac_id` is your primary key. Perhaps your problem is that `$ot_id` isn't defined. Try using `$data->ac_id` instead. Enable error reporting and see if the queries are running correctly using logic something like: `if (!$con->query($sql){printf("Error: %s\n", $con->error);}` also check that your SELECT query does indeed return rows: `echo $qry99->num_rows;`. Report back your findings.

Comment: Also I found an error in my first snippet with one too many `{`, sorry about that. If you had error reporting enabled, you'd have easily caught that.

Comment: Like I've said before, everything's fine and working. It's all about the logic on how to insert data from one table to another. It's the about `fetch_assoc()`. It should be `fetch_array()` and everything will work. Thanks mate :)

Comment: Edit your answer and replace `fetch_assoc()` to `fetch_array()` and I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: I don't see why this change would matter, so I accepted your edit suggestion. Either should work.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm referring to my own code. Yours would work either of the two.